Queue new create permission
My customer want a profile with team lead who is with non admin profile should be able to create a new queue.
Is it possible to create a new Queue by a non Admin?
I created new permission set with "manage user" enabled but it doesn't works, as i can't see any permission for Queue object for newly created permission set.
Do anyone have any idea can we have a permission set for a user to enable him for creating new queue?
If possible can you please share the steps that need to be considered to get the create new queue enabled.

As per this article , for queue creation we need below permissions, irrespective of admin/non-admin user:

Customize Application
Manage Public List Views

But for giving above permissions , we need Salesforce license since most of the other license types do not give permission for accessing setup objects.
Also ,there is no specific permissions for queue creation and above permissions will have other effects as well.
You can leave the license type field blank while creating permission set & try user(s) with different license types for confirming the valid licenses. (IMO only Salesforce license works , just checked few types)
